# Two decreasing, convex functions agreeing on a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

Fix a closed subset $B$ of $[0,\infty)$ and assume that $0\in B$. I am striving to construct two functions $f,g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that

- $f(0)=g(0)=1$;
- $f(x)\geq 0$ and $g(x)\geq0$ for each $x\geq 0$;
- $f$ and $g$ are continuous;
- $f$ and $g$ are non-increasing;
- $f$ and $g$ are convex; and
- $f(x)=g(x)$ if **and only if** $x\in B$.

I was thinking about using [Tietze’s extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), but that doesn’t say anything about algebraic properties (*i.e.*, convexity). Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you seek a family of examples (example for every possible closed $B$ that we can choose) or one example for one particular $B$ or one example for every possible $B$? Or something else? I am not sure if i understand your question.

Comment: $B$ is an arbitrary, fixed closed set. I want to show the existence of functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying these properties for this fixed $B$.

Comment: So, for example, $B$ could be Cantor set also, right?

Comment: @Farewell Yes, $B$ could the Cantor set, $[0,1]$, or any other subset of $[0,\infty)$ as long as it’s closed and contains the origin. I don’t want to impose further restrictions.

Comment: The complement of $B$ is a countable union of disjoint intervals. Let $f(x)=e^{-x}$. This fixes $g$ on $B$. Extend $g$ to the complement of $B$ via linear interpolation on the intervals.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, that’s the idea I had and also reflected in David C. Ulrich’s answer. However, since countably many modifications are made, checking continuity formally is a little tedious. I was hoping there was a clever way around this...

Comment: For continuity one can show that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|$ and that the construction of $g$ preserves this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of $B$ is a countable union of intervals $$I_n=(a_n,b_n),$$with $a_n,b_n\in B$, plus possibly $I_\omega=(a_\omega,\infty)$ with $a_\omega\in B$, if $B$ is bounded.

Let $f$ be $e^{-x}$ or $1/(x+1)$ or whatever strictly convex decreasing function you like. Let $g|_B=f|_B$, and on $\overline I_n$ let $g$ be the straight line such that $g(a_n)=f(a_n)$ and $g(b_n)=f(b_n)$. Make some other modification on $I_\omega$ if it's there...

Comment: @DavidC.Ulrich I did think about this. Right, $g$ can be just “flattened out” on $I_{\omega}$. My only concern is that even though the function $g$ is clearly continuous on the complement of $B$ (linearity), I have found it tedious to check the continuity of $g$ at any point in $B$. After all, the intervals $I_n$ may accumulate up around some point in $x\in B$, which makes it a little difficult to check the continuity of $g$ at $x$. [cont’d]

Comment: @DavidC.Ulrich The convexity of $g$ is more straightforward: if $f$ is altered on only a finite number of intervals, then the resulting function is convex by a straightforward graphical arguments (although the formalities are a little tedious), and the $g$ changed on all intervals is just the pointwise supremum of the functions corresponding to modifications on only a finite number of intervals, and hence $g$ is convex. At any rate, I very much appreciate your answer.

Comment: @triple_sec The continuity seems obvious to me, because both functions are decreasing. You can give a careful proof along the same lines as your argument for convexity: Say $g_n$ is $f$ after modification on $I_1,\dots,I_n$. Then $|g_n-g_{n-1}|\le f(a_n)-f(b_n)$ everywhere. And $f$ decreasing shows that $\sum(f(a_n)-f(b_n))<\infty$. So $(g_n)$ converges uniformly.

Comment: @triple_sec Or, come to think of it, recall that any convex function (defined on an open interval) is continuous. (To get continuity at $0$, start with a function defined on $[-1,\infty)$ instead of $[0,\infty)$, and pretend that $[-1,0]\subset B$ during the construction.)

Comment: @triple_sec You say the formalities for verifying that $g_n$ are convex are tedious. Nope. In fact $g_n$ is the supremum of a certain finite family of convex functions (namely $f$ and a few straight lines).

Comment: You’re right, I just didn’t have enough patience to think about tricks that can make it possible to circumvent checking continuity and convexity of the limit function directly. Thank you for your exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = h(x)+\mathbf{1}\{x \in B\}e^{-x},g(x) =e^{-x}$ and choose $h(x)$ convex decreasing such that $h(x) = e^{-x}$ on the boundaries of $B$ but nowhere else?

Comment: I am sorry, but I fail to see how $f$ can be continuous, convex, or even monotonic...

Comment: Huh? Just choose $h$ such that it's convex and monotonic and lies above $e^{-x}$, something like $e^{-x/2} +c$ will do, where $c$ is set to agree with $e^{-x}$ on the boundary of $B$...